# VBA extract percentage number

Tags: vba, formatting

I need to extract the percentage number from cell A1.
The content in the cell varies, it could be `"20% (Less applicable fees and taxes)"`, or pure number like `90%`, or `100%`. I will later use the number to perform some calculation.

My idea was to firstly get the position of `%`, so I can get the number.

However, if it is a pure number, I will not be able to get the position of the percentage mark because the value of range A1 is 0.9 or 1.

If it is not a pure number, I would be able to get the position of the percentage and extract the percentage number, but it is a string, I can't use it to perform calculation.

Can anyone give me an idea? thank you very much in advance!

Comment: The `.Text` property returns a formatted string even when the contents are numeric.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the cell string value with Range.Text.

```
Dim rg1 As Range
Dim rg2 As Range

Set rg1 = Range("A1")   '20% (Less applicable fees and taxes)
Set rg2 = Range("A2")   '90%

Debug.Print rg1.Value
Debug.Print rg2.Value

Debug.Print Val(Left(rg1.Text, InStr(1, rg1.Text, "%", vbBinaryCompare) - 1))
Debug.Print Val(Left(rg2.Text, InStr(1, rg2.Text, "%", vbBinaryCompare) - 1))
```

Output:

```
20% (Less applicable fees and taxes)
 0,9 

 20 
 90
```

Comment: The problem with `.Text` is that if you reduce the width of the column to 3.14 so the 90% shows as ### then the ### is the `.Text` value of the cell.  Maybe check if the value of the cell is numeric - if it is then there's no text and can be pulled with no problem, otherwise pull the characters to the left of the %.

Comment: You are right about that. Another idea is to check for `.NumberFormat`. If that is "0%" the cell value can be multiplied by 100.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RegEx`, which will allow you to extract just the numeric portion of whatever string.

```
Sub GetPercentageNumber()    

' RegEx variables
Dim RegNum As Object
Dim RegMatches As Variant
Dim myText As String
Dim GetPercentageNumber As Double


myText = "20% (Less applicable fees and taxes)"  ' <-- for testing purposes

' Late binding of setting RegEx object
Set RegNum = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
   
' to remove all non-digits
With RegNum
    .Pattern = "(\d+\.\d+)" ' Match any decimal value
    .Global = True
End With
              
' check if a cell with a decimal value
Set RegMatches = RegNum.Execute(myText)
If RegMatches.Count >= 1 Then ' make sure there is at least 1 match
    GetPercentageNumber = RegMatches(RegMatches.Count - 1)

Else ' failed to retrieve a decimal value --> check if a String with a %
    ' to remove all non digits
    With RegNum
        .Pattern = "\d{1,9}" ' Match any set of 1 to 9 digits
        .Global = True
    End With
    
    Set RegMatches = RegNum.Execute(myText)
    If RegMatches.Count >= 1 Then ' make sure there is at least 1 match
        GetPercentageNumber = RegMatches(RegMatches.Count - 1)
    End If
End If
  
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this using the cell equation `=IF(ISNUMBER(A1),A1,VALUE(LEFT(A1,FIND("%",A1,1))))`

[image: scr1]

The trick is the use `ISNUMBER()` to find out if the contents are numeric or not.

In VBA you can use the `IsNumeric()` function to do the same.